1 Corinthians 7:10-11 and the Grounds for Divorce and Remarriage

10 But to the married I give instructions, not I, but the Lord, that
the wife is not to leave her husband; 11 (but if she does leave, she
must remain unmarried, or else be reconciled to her husband), and that
the husband is not to divorce his wife. (1 Corinthians 7:10-11, NASB
2020)

In verse 10, Paul instructs the married not to divorce, referring to what Jesus taught, which can be found in:

Matthew 5:32, early in His ministry (Sermon on the Mount)
Luke 16:18, during His Galilean ministry
Matthew 19:9 (and Mark 10:11-12), while traveling to Jerusalem

Paul does not reveal the specific grounds for divorce he has in mind; he simply instructs the believers not to divorce.
In verse 11, Paul also forbids divorced believers from remarrying, instructing them to either remain divorced or reconcile.
He seems to confirm what Jesus said about divorce: there is a type of divorce initiated by men and approved by God, and another type initiated by men but disapproved by God. The latter would explain why believers should not remarry.
He seems to concede and make a provision for divorce: remain as you are or reconcile.
Paul seems to suggest that the grounds for divorce he has in mind do not allow remarriage, which could be for reasons other than sexual immorality (selfishness, pride, laziness, lying, etc.). Alternatively, he could be suggesting that the ground in question is sexual immorality, but because we should forgive one another as Jesus forgave our sins, even if the marriage has been broken due to adultery, we are called to forgive one another in His Kingdom and should never escalate to remarriage. Forgiveness must prevail as it can cover a multitude of sins, including adultery.
Paul could be forbidding remarriage:

On ANY divorce ground EXCEPT sexual immorality, such as selfishness, pride, laziness, lying, etc.
On ANY divorce ground INCLUDING sexual immorality, such as adultery as v10 seems to be a general commandment.

Questions:

How do you reconcile the exception clause in Matthew 5:32 and 19:9 that allows remarriage, with 1 Corinthians 7:10-11 where Paul says the believing spouses who divorced must not remarry?
If Paul considers divorce to be a sin, why does he not confront the divorcer(s) and apply disciplinary steps found in Matthew 18:15-17?
Can we assume which ground(s) for divorce and no remarriage Paul had in mind?


1. How do you reconcile the exception clause in Matthew 5:32 and 19:9 that allows remarriage, with 1 Corinthians 7:10-11 where Paul says the believing spouses who divorced must not remarry?

Matthew logically discusses adultery:
Mat 5:32 But I say to you that everyone who divorces his wife, except on the ground of (already being an adulterer), makes her (become an adulterer), and whoever marries a divorced woman (is an adulterer).
Mat 19:9 And I say to you: whoever divorces his wife, except for sexual immorality, and marries another, (is an adulterer).
I see nothing here that "allows remarriage".  Instead, it is allocating first cause blame for each becoming an adulterer(sinner).
Paul's instructions in 1 Cor 7:10-11 are on how to deal with marital problems without either party becoming an adulterer.
2. If Paul considers divorce to be a sin, why does he not confront the divorcer(s) and apply disciplinary steps found in Matthew 18:15-17?

Here Paul is laying out a principal, possibly because of a question or innuendo in the church. Do you see evidence that he has specific people/marriages in mind?  It seems that his goal is to keep situations from happening which might require discipline.
3. Can we assume which ground(s) for divorce and no remarriage Paul had in mind?

No. It seems that anything that would make it unbearable for the wife to stay with the man might be cause for separation.  But a man is not to choose to quit his responsibilities(via divorce).  Paul lays down general rules in 1 Cor 7, but these are not specifically intended to handle every hard case that comes up.  For instance, in v11,the wife may separate and remain unmarried, but how does that fit with conjugal rights in v 5? or the unbeliever  in v13 or v15?
When we nitpik this topic, is it because we want to judge others, or because of our own desires and the hardness of our heart (Mat 19:8)?

Up-voted +1. You have not covered (and had no need as it was not asked) the matter of the man whose wife voluntarily leaves him and remains unreconciled. She is to remain 'unmarried'. Which dissolves the marriage and leaves the man free to find another wife. Such are better to remain single (it is always better to be single) 'but and if he has married he has not sinned'.

[1Co 7:15 ESV] 15 But if the unbelieving partner separates, let it be so. In such cases the brother or sister is not enslaved. God has called you to peace.  note that this is for unbelieverers, implying that for believers (both are believers), they would both remain unmarried, or be reconciled.

'Art thou loosed from a wife ? Seek not a wife. But and if thou hast married thou hast not sinned.' Note this is to the man. Of the woman she is bound to her husband as long as her husband liveth. So, bound, she remains unmarried if she departs and is not reconciled. Paul proscribes differently for the man and the woman.

Mat 19:6 ...no longer two but one flesh. What therefore God has joined together, let not man separate."   A man remains one flesh (married) to  his first wife.  Taking a second living wife disqualifies one from the office of Deacon, Elder, or Bishop, (1 Tim 3:2, 3:12, Tit 1.6), which indicates how problematic this is.  The only scripture for having a second wife provides for care of a brother's widow. Taking a second wife will almost always lead to treachery against the first wife.
Mal 2:15  ...Therefore take heed to your spirit, and let none deal treacherously against the wife of his youth.


Elders are not required to be the husband of one wife. Deacon/bishop, yes. 2. If a woman leaves a husband and becomes unmarried then there is no marriage. He is 'loosed' from a wife. He does not take a 'second wife'. He is the husband of one wife. You are thinking along traditional lines and not seeing what is there in scripture.


Nigel: Elder per Titus 1:5,6.  How do you explain away Jesus words in Mat 19:6?

Bishops, verse 7, are ordained from out of the  presbytery, verse 5. 'Ordain an elder' means to ordain one out of the prebytery - to be a bishop, to oversee. Elders are merely that, elderly men. In every city, Titus was to choose, out of the presbytery of elders, singular men of outstanding character and perception, to oversee, from within the eldership, the whole assembly. Again, you are following traditions and not seeing what the scripture is actually saying..

Matthew 19:6. Indeed, no man is to put asunder and  no man can. If a woman leaves a man she must remain unmarried. She cannot break that bond. She is still bound by the law to her husband as long as the husband liveth. But there is no scripture that prevents a man, if the marriage is thus ended (she is 'unmarried') to take another woman. And if deacons and bishops must be the husband of one wife, it follows that there were, in the church, men with more than one. Else, there were no need to say it as it would already be mandatory. Yet again, tradition. Yet again, scripture.

I am not 'explaining away' anything. I am expressing what is plainly there on the page of scripture. And you are requiring that if a woman abandons a husband, then he must remain celibate until she dies . . . . . . . which scripture does not require (but tradition does, to the detriment of many).

What if you are wrong in your interpretation? Once you become one flesh, that does not change. A legal status, e.g. divorce, does not change that.  Why is it so important to you to have a right to multiple spouses?  Jesus tells us that Moses allowed divorce because of our hardness of heart.  I contend that your insistence is likewise based on hardness of heart, and denial of the one flesh principle, which is not negated by mere separation.

I think you are now just repeating what you have already said, which I have already answered, so I think it is time to end our discussion. Plus the system has just prompted me to not extend comment.

First, let us remind ourselves of some inescapable legal realities:

Under Roman law in the 1st century, a woman could not divorce her husband - only a husband could divorce his wife to dissolve the marriage
the husband needed almost not excuse for divorce; husbands were permitted (under Roman law) to divorce their wives on the flimsiest excuses, including a whim of simple displeasure
In some circumstances, some women (like today) lived under intolerable circumstances, simply separated from their husbands (without divorce!) to escape the domestic situation.  However, they remained legally married under such circumstances unless the husband decided to divorce.

It is for this reason that that Paul in 1 Cor 7 used the legally correct (for Roman law) of "separate" for the wife and "divorce" for the husband (V9, 10).
Valid reasons for Biblical Divorce
According to the Scriptures as we have them the following are valid reasons for divorce.  Separation is permissible provided the parties do not remarry; or must reconcile.

Sexual immorality Matt 5:32, 19:9
If an unbelieving spouse leaves/separates/divorces, the believing partner is free, ie, not "bound".

Procedure of Matt 18:15-17
Let us examine the three-fold procedure for resolving differences in Matt 18:15-17.  Jesus' procedure here is essentially optimized for disputes between believers in the church and works well for that.
However, if we have a couple who divorces for reasons other than sexual immorality and one marries another spouse, then the procedure of Matt 18:15-17 would be counter-productive - breaking up another marriage to re-form the collapsed marriage is a formula for disaster.  Two wrongs do not make things right.
I suggest it is for this reason that Paul does not discuss this in 1 Cor 7.
Final Note
Note carefully what Jesus says in his advice about marriage in Matt 19 -

8 Jesus replied, “Moses permitted you to divorce your wives because of your hardness of heart; but it was not this way from the
beginning. 9 Now I tell you that whoever divorces his wife, except
for sexual immorality, and marries another woman, commits adultery.”
10 His disciples said to Him, “If this is the case between a man and his wife, it is better not to marry.”
11 “Not everyone can accept this word,” He replied, “but only those to whom it has been given. 12 For there are eunuchs who were
born that way; others were made that way by men; and still others live
like eunuchs for the sake of the kingdom of heaven. The one who can
accept this should accept it.”

Note the last two verses: "Not everyone can accept this word ... The one who can accept this should accept it.”  Thus, we cannot be hard and fast about these rules in the church.  For example; imagine a poor beaten wife who must endure abuse and beating several times per week for husband who is a church member (or elder); the husband has not committed any sexual immorality - should the wife leave?  Obviously she should leave to preserve her life and those of her children.
Thus, such marital rules should be administered in the church with both justice and compassion.

Sexual immorality, in Matt 19:9 and 5:32, does not refer to adultery after marriage.  It refers to fornication committed before the marriage by one of the partners which was discovered after the marriage was finalized.  A marriage was intended to be between two virgins and if one party discovered that the other was not a virgin divorce and remarriage was permitted for the injured party.  Technically it was not so much a divorce as an annulment because the marriage was not valid to begin with because fraud was involved.

@moron - quite the contrary - look at any lexicon - pornea refers to any illicit sex whether before or after marriage.
